# Isn't this optimization question unsolvable? We need to solve it without Simplex method.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Max Z = $x_1$
subject to
$a_jx_1 + x_{j+1} ≤ b_j$ for j = 1, 2, . . . , n
where $b ≥ 0, a > 0 , x ≥ 0$ are vectors of suitable sizes.

What I get is
$x_1 \le \frac{b_j - x_{j+1}}{a_j} $
Now if I substitute the value of j as 1, 2,.... what I get is just a bunch of further unknowns, how can I make a graph out of this or make any assumptions for its value?

Comment: This can be solved by hand. Note that $x \geq 0$, so you can get actual upper bounds for $x_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inspection, to make $x_1$ large, you want each $x_{j+1}$ to be small, so take $x_{j+1}=0$.  Now $x_1\le b_j/a_j$ for all $j$, so the maximum $x_1$ is $\min_j \{b_j/a_j\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was thinking along the right lines then, just didn't have a way to articulate it properly.